# Setup.exe file created with InstallShield is installed successfully but application doesnt update, it keeps previous installed version

Tags: installation, installshield, major-upgrade, installshield-2018

Problem I'm facing is that Setup.exe with new app version is successfully installed but previous version that exists is not upgraded.

When I run the application it opens in previous version(4.5), but in control panel next to the app name stands new application's version number(4.6). There is no two instances in Control Panel.

Setup.exe file is created using InstallShield 2018 Express.
In Upgrade Paths I've added new path created from my previous setup.exe file.
The upgrade code is same as for previous versions, and in General Information I've updated the Product Code.

For "Max Version" number I've tried with 4.6, 4.5.1, 5.0 and allways the same problem appears.

"Include Min Version" is set to No

I've done this several times in the past successfully but for some reason this time it doesn't work.

With same setup.exe file application is successfully installed from scratch, but when previous version exists it doesn't work as expected.

None of the solutions I found online worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your main application (executable?) is not getting upgraded. Make sure that you're logging the install. Then after the install completes search the log for the Component GUID of the executable not upgrading to search for clues.

One other thing to check for is a pending reboot. If the application was in use it may not upgrade until a reboot happens.

Comment: I did check the logs, but not really sure what to look for. It' pretty much seems the same as one when upgrade is successful. Also tried with reboot, doesn't help either.

It's interesting that  when I moved installation project to different PC, then the setup created on that machine upgrades the version that was not getting upgraded with setup created on PC before, but now it doesn't work over some older versions. So when different PC is used problem still exists but over different app versions.

Comment: Find the ComponentGUID being used for your executable which is not getting upgraded. This will be in the Component table. You should be able to see this in the Component table when you go into Direct View within InstallShield. Search the log for that GUID. On one of the lines with this GUID you'll see "action" and what it did with this component and possibly why.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this with click on "Resequence RemoveExistingProducts" button in "Upgrade Paths" tab.

Somehow this order of installing/removing product was changed.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWDnu.png)